# Is there any verse or mantra to become opulent?

Tags: mantras

Is there any verse or mantra to become opulent, rich , magnificent and wealthy?

Comment: I'm not sure about the scriptures having such verse but I think the answer is no because if there was any verse which makes a person wealthy then by now, all the 7 billion people on earth would be super rich.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria, there is no reason for all 7 billion people to know or believe or chant such verses. So, you cannot dismiss the existence of such mantras just because poor people exist

Comment: Any slokas related to Kubera or Lakshmi are supposed to  give wealth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their is similar shloka , I have found relating to your question. Their may be many more shlokas or mantras similar to this , but it I find this more closely related to question.

> श्रद्धां मेधां यशः प्रज्ञां विद्यां बुद्धिं श्रियं बलम् ।  आयुष्यं तेज
>   आरोग्यं देहि मे हव्यवाहन ॥ ॥
>
> O  Messenger (Agni) give me faith, wisdom, glory, understanding,
>   learning, intellect, wealth, power, longetivity, lusture, and health..

Comment: @Parth Trivedi Unfortunately I don't know the source or whether this verse can be called as mantra or not.

Answer (score 4):

There is a famous Rigveda khila part [Sri Suktam](http://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/stotram/maha-lakshmi/translation/shree-suktam-with-lakshmi-suktam.html) is available. By chanting this one can become wealthy and glorious.

But the effect of mantras only depends upon faith, devotion and method of chanting.

> हरिः ॐ हिरण्यवर्णां हरिणीं सुवर्णरजतस्र​जाम् ।
>   चन्द्रां हिरण्मयीं लक्ष्मीं जातवेदो म आवह ॥१॥
>
> 1.1: Who is of Golden Colour, Beautiful and Adorned with Gold and Silver Garlands. (Gold represents Sun or the Fire of Tapas; Silver represents Moon or the Bliss and Beauty of Pure Sattva.)
>
> 1.2: Who is like the Moon with a Golden Aura, Who is Lakshmi, the Embodiment of Sri; O Jatavedo, please Invoke for Me that Lakshmi. (Moon represents the Bliss and Beauty of Pure Sattva and the Golden Aura represents the Fire of Tapas.)
>
> तां म आवह जातवेदो लक्ष्मीमनपगामिनीम् ।
>   यस्यां हिरण्यं विन्देयं गामश्वं पुरुषानहम् ॥२॥
>
> 2.1: (Harih Om) O Jatavedo, Invoke for Me that Lakshmi, Who does not Go Away, (Sri is Non-Moving, All-Pervasive and the Underlying Essence of All Beauty. Devi Lakshmi as the Embodiment of Sri is thus Non-Moving in Her essential nature.)
>
> 2.2: **By Whose Golden Touch, I will Obtain Cattle, Horses, Progeny and Servants**. (Golden Touch represents the Fire of Tapas which manifests in us as the Energy of Effort by the Grace of the Devi. Cattle, Horses etc are external manifestations of Sri following the effort.)
>
> अश्वपूर्वां रथमध्यां हस्तिनादप्रबोधिनीम् ।
>   श्रियं देवीमुपह्वये श्रीर्मा देवी जुषताम् ॥३॥
>
> 3.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Who is Abiding in the Chariot of Sri ( in the Middle ) which is driven by Horses in Front and Whose Appearance is Heralded by the Trumpet of Elephants, (Chariot represents the Abode of Sri and Horses represents the Energy of Effort. The Trumpet of Elephants represents the Awakening of Wisdom.)
>
> 3.2: Invoke the Devi who is the Embodiment of Sri Nearer so that the Devi of Prosperity becomes Pleased with Me. (Prosperity is the external manifestation of Sri and is therefore pleased when Sri is Invoked.)
>
> कां सोस्मितां हिरण्यप्राकारामार्द्रां ज्वलन्तीं तृप्तां तर्पयन्तीम् ।
>   पद्मे स्थितां पद्मवर्णां तामिहोपह्वये श्रियम् ॥४॥
>
> 4.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Who is Having a Beautiful Smile and Who is Enclosed by a Soft Golden Glow; **Who is eternally Satisfied and Satisfies all those to whom She Reveals Herself**, (Beautiful Smile represents the Trancendental Beauty of Sri Who is Enclosed by the Golden Glow of the Fire of Tapas.)
>
> 4.2: Who Abides in the Lotus and has the Colour of the Lotus; (O Jatavedo) Invoke that Lakshmi Here, Who is the Embodiment of Sri. (Lotus represents the Lotus of Kundalini.)
>
> प्रभासां यशसा लोके देवजुष्टामुदाराम् ।
>   पद्मिनीमीं शरणमहं प्रपद्येऽलक्ष्मीर्मे नश्यतां त्वां वृणे ॥५॥
>
> 5.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Who is the Embodiment of Sri and Whose Glory Shines like the Splendour of the Moon in all the Worlds; Who is Noble and Who is Worshipped by the Devas.)
>
> 5.2: I take Refuge at Her Feet, Who Abides in the Lotus; **By Her Grace, let the Alakshmi (in the form of Evil, Distress and Poverty) within and without be Destroyed**. (Lotus represents the Lotus of Kundalini.)
>
> आदित्यवर्णे तपसोऽधिजातो वनस्पतिस्तव वृक्षोऽथ बिल्वः ।
>   तस्य फलानि तपसानुदन्तु मायान्तरायाश्च बाह्या अलक्ष्मीः ॥६॥
>
> 6.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Who is of the Colour of the Sun and Born of Tapas; the Tapas which is like a Huge Sacred Bilva Tree, (The Golden Colour of the Sun represents the Fire of Tapas.)
>
> 6.2: Let the Fruit of That Tree of Tapas Drive Away the Delusion and Ignorance Within and the Alakshmi (in the form of Evil, Distress and Poverty) Outside.
>
> उपैतु मां देवसखः कीर्तिश्च मणिना सह ।
>   प्रादुर्भूतोऽस्मि राष्ट्रेऽस्मिन् कीर्तिमृद्धिं ददातु मे ॥७॥
>
> 7.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) **By Whose Presence will Come Near me the Companions of the Devas along with Glory (Inner Prosperity) and various Jewels (Outer Prosperity)**,
>
> 7.2: And I will be Reborn in the Realm of Sri (signifying Inner Transformation towards Purity) **which will Grant me Inner Glory and Outer Prosperity**.
>
> क्षुत्पिपासामलां ज्येष्ठामलक्ष्मीं नाशयाम्यहम् ।
>   अभूतिमसमृद्धिं च सर्वां निर्णुद गृहात् ॥८॥
>
> 8.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Whose Presence will Destroy Hunger, Thirst and Impurity associated with Her Elder Sister Alakshmi,
>
> 8.2: And Drive Away the Wretchedness and Ill-Fortune from My House.
>
> गन्धद्वारां दुराधर्षां नित्यपुष्टां करीषिणीम् ।
>   ईश्वरींग् सर्वभूतानां तामिहोपह्वये श्रियम् ॥९॥
>
> 9.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Who is the Source of All Fragrances, Who is Difficult to Approach, Who is Always Filled with Abundance and leaves a Residue of Abundance wherever She Reveals Herself.
>
> 9.2: Who is the Ruling Power in All Beings; (O Jatavedo) Please Invoke Her Here, Who is the Embodiment of Sri.
>
> मनसः काममाकूतिं वाचः सत्यमशीमहि ।
>   पशूनां रूपमन्नस्य मयि श्रीः श्रयतां यशः ॥१०॥
>
> 10.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) For Whom my Heart Truly Yearns and to Whom my Speech Truly tries to Reach,
>
> 10.2: **By Whose Presence will come Cattle, Beauty and Food in my Life as (External) Prosperity** and Who will Reside (i.e. Reveal) in me as (Inner) Glory of Sri.
>
> कर्दमेन प्रजाभूता सम्भव कर्दम ।
>   श्रियं वासय मे कुले मातरं पद्ममालिनीम् ॥११॥
>
> 11.1: (Harih Om. O Kardama, Invoke for me your Mother) As Kardama ( referring to Earth represented by Mud ) acts as the substratum for the Existence of Mankind, Similarly O Kardama (now referring to sage Kardama, the son of Devi Lakshmi) you Stay with me,
>
> 11.2: And be the cause to bring your Mother to Dwell in My Family; Your Mother who is the Embodiment of Sri and Encircled by Lotuses.
>
> आपः सृजन्तु स्निग्धानि चिक्लीत वस गृहे ।
>   नि च देवी मातरं श्रियं वासय कुले ॥१२॥
>
> 12.1: (Harih Om. O Chiklita, Invoke for me your Mother) As Chiklita ( referring to Moisture represented by Water ) Creates Loveliness in all things by its presence, similarly O Chiklita (now referring to Chiklita, the son of Devi Lakshmi) you Stay with me,
>
> 12.2: And by your presence bring your Mother, the Devi who is the Embodiment of Sri (and essence of all Loveliness) to Dwell in my Family.
>
> आर्द्रां पुष्करिणीं पुष्टिं पिङ्गलां पद्ममालिनीम् ।
>   चन्द्रां हिरण्मयीं लक्ष्मीं जातवेदो म आवह ॥१३॥
>
> 13.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Who is like the Moisture of a Lotus Pond which Nourishes a Soul (with Her Soothing Loveliness); and Who is Encircled by Light Yellow Lotuses,
>
> 13.2: Who is like a Moon with a Golden Aura; O Jatavedo, please Invoke that Lakshmi for me. (Devi Lakshmi in the form of a Moon represents the Transcendental Bliss and Beauty of Sri. This Soothing Loveliness is compared with the Moisture of a Lotus Pond which Nourishes a Soul. )
>
> आर्द्रां यः करिणीं यष्टिं सुवर्णां हेममालिनीम् ।
>   सूर्यां हिरण्मयीं लक्ष्मीं जातवेदो म आवह ॥१४॥
>
> 14.1: (Harih Om. O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi) Who is like the Moisture (figuratively representing Energy) which Supports the Performance of Activities; and Who is Encircled by Gold (Glow of the Fire of Tapas),
>
> 14.2: Who is like a Sun with a Golden Aura; O Jatavedo, please Invoke that Lakshmi for me. (Devi Lakshmi in the form of a Sun represents the Fire of Tapas. This Fire is compared with the moisture within activities, the moisture figuratively signifying energy. The Fire of Tapas manifests as the Energy of Activities.)
>
> तां म आवह जातवेदो लक्ष्मीमनपगामिनीम् ।
>   यस्यां हिरण्यं प्रभूतं गावो दास्योऽश्वान् विन्देयं पूरुषानहम् ॥१५॥
>
> 15.1: (Harih Om). O Jatavedo, Invoke for me that Lakshmi, Who does not Go Away, (Sri is Non-Moving, All-Pervasive and the Underlying Essence of All Beauty. Devi Lakshmi as the Embodiment of Sri is thus Non-Moving in Her essential nature.)
>
> 15.2: **By Whose Golden Touch I will obtain (i.e. Sri will be manifested as) Abundant Cattle, Servants, Horses and Progeny**. (Golden Touch represents the Fire of Tapas which manifests in us as the Energy of Effort by the grace of the Devi. Cattle, Horses etc are external manifestations of Sri following the effort.)
>
> यः शुचिः प्रयतो भूत्वा जुहुयादाज्यमन्वहम् ।
>   सूक्तं पञ्चदशर्चं च श्रीकामः सततं जपेत् ॥१६॥
>
> 16.1: Those who after Becoming Bodily Clean and Devotionally Disposed perform Sacrificial Offering with Butter Day after Day,
>
> 16.2: By Constantly Reciting the Fifteen Verses of Sri Suktam will have their Longing for Sri Fulfilled by the Grace of Devi Lakshmi.
>
> पद्मानने पद्म ऊरु पद्माक्षी पद्मासम्भवे ।
>   त्वं मां भजस्व पद्माक्षी येन सौख्यं लभाम्यहम् ॥१७॥
>
> 17.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Whose Face is of Lotus, Who is supported (indicated by Thigh ) by Lotus, Whose Eyes are of Lotus and Who is Born of Lotus. (Lotus indicates Kundalini. Face indicates the nature of a person, thighs indicate support and eyes indicate the spiritual vision. This verse describes the transcendental nature of Mother Lakshmi. She is born of Yoga, united with Yoga and revealed to a devotee in his spiritual vision.)
>
> 17.2: O Mother, You manifest in Me in the Spiritual Vision (indicated by Lotus Eyes ) born of intense Devotion by Which I am filled with (i.e. Obtain ) Divine Bliss.
>
> अश्वदायि गोदायि धनदायि महाधने ।
>   धनं मे जुषताम् देवी सर्वकामांश्च देहि मे ॥१८॥
>
> 18.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) **Who is the Giver of Horses, Cows and Wealth to all**; and Who is the Source of the Great Abundance in this World.
>
> 18.2: **O Devi, Please be Gracious to grant Wealth** (both inner and outer) to Me and Fulfil All my Aspirations.
>
> पुत्रपौत्र धनं धान्यं हस्त्यश्वादिगवे रथम् ।
>   प्रजानां भवसि माता आयुष्मन्तं करोतु माम् ॥१९॥
>
> 19.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) **O Mother, bestow us with Children and Grandchildren to continue our lineage; and Wealth, Grains, Elephants, Horses, Cows and Carriages for our daily use**.
>
> 19.2: We Are Your Children, O Mother; Please make our lives Long and full of Vigour.
>
> धनमग्निर्धनं वायुर्धनं सूर्यो धनं वसुः ।
>   धनमिन्द्रो बृहस्पतिर्वरुणं धनमश्नुते ॥२०॥
>
> 20.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) O Mother, You (indicated by Dhanam) are the Power behind Agni (the God of Fire), You are the Power behind Vayu (the God of Wind), You are the Power behind Surya (the God of Sun), You are the Power behind the Vasus (celestial beings).
>
> 20.2: You are the Power behind Indra, Vrhaspati and Varuna (the God of Water); You are the All-Pervading Essence behind Everything.
>
> वैनतेय सोमं पिब सोमं पिबतु वृत्रहा ।
>   सोमं धनस्य सोमिनो मह्यं ददातु ॥२१॥
>
> 21.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Those who carry Sri Vishnu in their Heart (like Garuda, the son of Vinata carries Him on his back) always drink Soma (the Divine Bliss within); Let all Drink that Soma by Destroying their inner Enemies of desires (thus gaining nearness to Sri Vishnu).
>
> 21.2: That Soma originates from Sri Who is the embodiment of Soma (the Divine Bliss); O Mother, please Give that Soma to Me too, You Who are the possessor of that Soma.
>
> न क्रोधो न च मात्सर्य न लोभो नाशुभा मतिः ।
>   भवन्ति कृतपुण्यानां भक्तानां श्रीसूक्तं जपेत्सदा ॥२२॥
>
> 22.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Neither Anger Nor Jealousy, Neither Greed Nor Evil Intentions ...
>
> 22.2: Can Exist in the Devotees who have acquired Merit by Always Reciting with Devotion the great Sri Suktam.
>
> वर्षन्तु ते विभावरि दिवो अभ्रस्य विद्युतः ।
>   रोहन्तु सर्वबीजान्यव ब्रह्म द्विषो जहि ॥२३॥
>
> 23.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) O Mother, Please Shower Your Light of Grace like Lightning in a Sky filled with Thunder-Cloud...
>
> 23.2: And Ascend All the Seeds of Differentiation to a higher spiritual plane; O Mother, You are of the nature of Brahman and Destroyer of all Hatred.
>
> पद्मप्रिये पद्म पद्महस्ते पद्मालये पद्मदलायताक्षि ।
>   विश्वप्रिये विष्णु मनोऽनुकूले त्वत्पादपद्मं मयि सन्निधत्स्व ॥२४॥
>
> 24.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Who is Fond of Lotuses, Who is the Possessor of Lotuses, Who Holds Lotuses in Her Hands, Who Dwells in the Abode of Lotuses and Whose Eyes are like Lotus Petals. (Lotus indicates Kundalini)
>
> 24.2: Who is Fond of the Worldly Manifestations which are Directed towards (i.e. Agreeable to) Sri Vishnu (i.e. follows the path of Dharma); O Mother, bless me so that I Gain Nearness to Your Lotus Feet Within Me.
>
> या सा पद्मासनस्था विपुलकटितटी पद्मपत्रायताक्षी ।
>   गम्भीरा वर्तनाभिः स्तनभर नमिता शुभ्र वस्त्रोत्तरीया ॥२५॥
>
> 25.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Who Stands on Lotus with Her Beautiful Form, with Wide Hip and Eyes like the Lotus Leaf.
>
> 25.2: Her Deep Navel (indicating Depth of Character) is Bent Inwards, and with Her Full Bosom (indicating Abundance and Compassion) She is slightly Bent Down (towards the Devotees); and She is Dressed in Pure White Garments.
>
> लक्ष्मीर्दिव्यैर्गजेन्द्रैर्मणिगणखचितैस्स्नापिता हेमकुम्भैः ।
>   नित्यं सा पद्महस्ता मम वसतु गृहे सर्वमाङ्गल्ययुक्ता ॥२६॥
>
> 26.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Who is Bathed with Water from Golden Pitcher by the Best of Celestial Elephants who are Studded with Various Gems,
>
> 26.2: Who is Eternal with Lotus in Her Hands; Who is United with All the Auspicious Attributes; O Mother, Please Reside in My House and make it Auspicious by Your Presence.
>
> लक्ष्मीं क्षीरसमुद्र राजतनयां श्रीरङ्गधामेश्वरीम् ।
>   दासीभूतसमस्त देव वनितां लोकैक दीपांकुराम् ॥२७॥
>
> 27.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Who is the Daughter of the King of Ocean; Who is the Great Goddess Residing in Kseera Samudra (literally Milky Ocean), the Abode of Sri Vishnu.
>
> 27.2: Who is Served by the Devas along with their Servants, and Who is the One Light in all the Worlds which Sprouts behind every Manifestation.
>
> श्रीमन्मन्दकटाक्षलब्ध विभव ब्रह्मेन्द्रगङ्गाधराम् ।
>   त्वां त्रैलोक्य कुटुम्बिनीं सरसिजां वन्दे मुकुन्दप्रियाम् ॥२८॥
>
> 28.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) By Obtaining Whose Grace through Her Beautiful Soft Glance, Lord Brahma, Indra and Gangadhara (Shiva) become Great,
>
> 28.2: O Mother, You blossom in the Three Worlds like a Lotus as the Mother of the Vast Family; You are Praised by All and You are the Beloved of Mukunda.
>
> सिद्धलक्ष्मीर्मोक्षलक्ष्मीर्जयलक्ष्मीस्सरस्वती ।
>   श्रीलक्ष्मीर्वरलक्ष्मीश्च प्रसन्ना मम सर्वदा ॥२९॥
>
> 29.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) O Mother, May Your different Forms - Siddha Lakshmi, Moksha Lakshmi, Jaya Lakshmi, Saraswati...
>
> 29.2: Sri Lakshmi and Vara Lakshmi ... Always be Gracious to Me.
>
> वरांकुशौ पाशमभीतिमुद्रां करैर्वहन्तीं कमलासनस्थाम् ।
>   बालार्क कोटि प्रतिभां त्रिणेत्रां भजेहमाद्यां जगदीस्वरीं त्वाम् ॥३०॥
>
> 30.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) From Your Four Hands - first in Vara Mudra ( Gesture of Boon-Giving ), second Holding Angkusha ( Hook ), third Holding a Pasha ( Noose ) and fourth in Abhiti Mudra ( Gesture of Fearlessness ) - Flows Boons, Assurance of Help during Obstacles, Assurance of Breaking our Bondages and Fearlessness; As You Stand on the Lotus (to shower grace on the devotees).
>
> 30.2: I Worship You, O Primordial Goddess of the Universe, from Whose Three Eyes Appear Millions of Newly Risen Suns (i.e. different worlds).
>
> सर्वमङ्गलमाङ्गल्ये शिवे सर्वार्थ साधिके ।
>   शरण्ये त्र्यम्बके देवि नारायणि नमोऽस्तु ते ॥३१॥
>
> 31.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Who is the Auspiciousness in All the Auspicious, Auspiciousness Herself and Complete with All the Auspicious Attributes,
>
> 31.2: I Salute You O Narayani, the Devi Who is the Giver of Refuge and with Three Eyes.
>
> सरसिजनिलये सरोजहस्ते धवलतरांशुक गन्धमाल्यशोभे ।
>   भगवति हरिवल्लभे मनोज्ञे त्रिभुवनभूतिकरि प्रसीद मह्यम् ॥३२॥
>
> 32.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) Who Abides in Lotus and Holds Lotus in Her Hands; Dressed in Dazzling White Garments and Decorated with the most Fragrant Garlands, She Radiates a Divine Aura,
>
> 32.2: O Goddess, You are Dearer than the Dearest of Hari and the most Captivating; You are the Source of Wellbeing and Prosperity of all the Three Worlds; O Mother, Please be Gracious to Me.
>
> विष्णुपत्नीं क्षमां देवीं माधवीं माधवप्रियाम् ।
>   विष्णोः प्रियसखीं देवीं नमाम्यच्युतवल्लभाम् ॥३३॥
>
> 33.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) O Devi, You are the Consort of Sri Vishnu and the embodiment of Forbearance; You are One with Madhava (in essence) and extremely Dear to Him.
>
> 33.2: I Salute You O Devi Who is the Dear Companion of Sri Vishnu and extremely Beloved of Acyuta (another name of Sri Vishnu literally meaning Infallible).
>
> महालक्ष्मी च विद्महे विष्णुपत्नीं च धीमहि ।
>   तन्नो लक्ष्मीः प्रचोदयात् ॥३४॥
>
> 34.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) May we Know the Divine Essence of Mahalakshmi by Meditating on Her, who is the Consort of Sri Vishnu,
>
> 34.2: Let That Divine Essence of Lakshmi Awaken our Spiritual Consciousness.
>
> श्रीवर्चस्यमायुष्यमारोग्यमाविधात् पवमानं महियते ।
>   धनं धान्यं पशुं बहुपुत्रलाभं शतसंवत्सरं दीर्घमायुः ॥३५॥
>
> 35.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) O Mother, Let Your Auspiciousness Flow in our lives as the Vital Power, making our lives Long and Healthy, and filled with Joy.
>
> 35.2: **And let Your Auspiciousness manifest around as Wealth, Grains, Cattle and Many Offsprings who live Happily for Hundred Years**; who live Happily throughout their Long Lives.
>
> ऋणरोगादिदारिद्र्यपापक्षुदपमृत्यवः ।
>   भयशोकमनस्तापा नश्यन्तु मम सर्वदा ॥३६॥
>
> 36.1: (Harih Om, Salutations to Mother Lakshmi) **O Mother, (please remove my) Debts, Illness, Poverty, Sins, Hunger and the possibility of Accidental Death** ...
>
> 36.2: and also remove my Fear, Sorrow and Mental Anguish; O Mother, Please Remove them Always.
>
> य एवं वेद ॐ महादेव्यै च विष्णुपत्नीं च धीमहि ।
>   तन्नो लक्ष्मीः प्रचोदयात् ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः ॥३७॥
>
> 37.1: This (the Essence of Mahalakshmi) Indeed is Veda (the ultimate Knowledge), May we Know the Divine Essence of the Great Devi by Meditating on Her, who is the Consort of Sri Vishnu,
>
> 37.2: Let That Divine Essence of Lakshmi Awaken our Spiritual Consciousness, Om Peace Peace Peace.

As suggested by [Moonstar in comments](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13840/is-there-any-verse-or-mantra-to-become-opulent/13912?noredirect=1#comment39075_13912) that Sri Suktam is a Vedic mantra and everyone cannot recite this. So, there is an alternative [Kanakadhara Stotra](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/kanaka-tr.html?lang=sa) composed by Shankaracharya.

> अङ्गं हरेः पुलकभूषणमाश्रयन्ती
>   भृङ्गाङ्गनेव मुकुलाभरणं तमालम् ।
>
> अङ्गीकृताखिलविभूतिरपाङ्गलीला
>   माङ्गल्यदाऽस्तु मम मङ्गलदेवतायाः ॥ १॥
>
> The dark Tamala tree in full bloom attracts the female
>   beetle and even so MahalakShmi is attracted and finds
>   happiness in the fragrant and dark-complexioned body
>   of Hari and makes it tingle with joy. May she bestow on
>   me prosperity by her auspicious glance.
>
> मुग्धा मुहुर्विदधती वदने मुरारेः
>   प्रेमत्रपाप्रणिहितानि गतागतानि ।
>
> माला दृशोर्मधुकरीव महोत्पले या
>   सा मे श्रियं दिशतु सागरसंभवायाः ॥ २॥
>
> The shy love-laden sidelong glance of the beauteous
>   dark eyes of the daughter oof the Milky Ocean, returns
>   again and again to the beauteous lotus face of Murari,
>   just like the black bee constantly returning and flitting
>   about the beautiful blue lotus flower. I pray that these
>   glances be bestowed upon me to bless me with prosperity.
>
> आमीलिताक्षमधिगम्य मुदा मुकुन्दं
>   आनन्दकन्दमनिमेषमनङ्गतन्त्रम् ।
>
> आकेकरस्थितकनीनिकपक्ष्मनेत्रं
>   भूत्यै भवेन्मम भुजङ्गशयाङ्गनायाः ॥ ३॥
>
> The eyes of Mukunda remain closed in ecstasy. The beauteous
>   dark eyes of LakShmi remain fixed on Mukunda in love and
>   wonder and remain open without blinking. May these eyes of
>   MahalakShmi fall on me and bless me with prosperity and happiness
>
> बाह्वन्तरे मधुजितः श्रितकौस्तुभे या
>   हारावलीव हरिनीलमयी विभाति ।
>
> कामप्रदा भगवतोऽपि कटाक्षमाला
>   कल्याणमावहतु मे कमलालयायाः ॥ ४॥
>
> Lord Vishnu whose chest is adorned by the Kaustubha
>   Mala is also adorned by the series of the beauteous
>   glances of Goddess MahalakShmi. This string of glances
>   resembles a necklace of precious blue stones of
>   Indraneela and they are capable of fulfilling all the wishes
>   of Hari Himself. May this string of glances be directed
>   towards me so that it will bring me auspiciousness
>
> कालाम्बुदालिललितोरसि कैटभारेः
>   धाराधरे स्फुरति या तडिदङ्गनेव ।
>
> मातुस्समस्तजगतां महनीयमूर्तिः
>   भद्राणि मे दिशतु भार्गवनन्दनायाः ॥ ५॥
>
> MahalakShmi shining on the dark broad chest of
>   Mahavishnu is like the streak of lightning illuminating
>   the dark rain clouds. May she, the daughter of the
>   Sage Bhargava worshipped as Mother by the entire
>   universe, bring me auspiciousness
>
> प्राप्तं पदं प्रथमतः खलु यत्प्रभावात्
>   माङ्गल्यभाजि मधुमाथिनि मन्मथेन ।
>
> मय्यापतेत्तदिह मन्थरमीक्षणार्धं
>   मन्दालसं च मकरालयकन्यकायाः ॥ ६॥
>
> The God of Love, Manmatha, could gain access to
>   Madhusudana (the destroyer of the demon Madhu, i.e.
>   Vishnu) only because he was favored with the blessing
>   glance from MahalakShmi . May her auspicious indolent
>   sideglance fall on me (May she bless me with prosperity
>   by looking at me in passing at least for a moment
>
> विश्वामरेन्द्रपदविभ्रमदानदक्षं
>   आनन्दहेतुरधिकं मुरविद्विषोऽपि ।
>
> ईषन्निषीदतु मयि क्षणमीक्षणार्धम्
>   इन्दीवरोदरसहोदरमिन्दिरायाः ॥ ७॥
>
> The status of the king of kings or the exal;ted position
>   of an Indra are given effortlessly by MahalakShmi by a mere
>   momentary glance. Murari (Vishnu) who is supreme bliss
>   itself is made happy by it. May this glance from the blue-
>   lotus eyes of LakShmi fall on me for a moment at least.
>
> दृष्ट्या त्रिविष्टपपदं सुलभं लभन्ते ।
>   दृष्टिः प्रहृष्टकमलोदरदीप्तिरिष्टां
>   पुष्टिं कृषीष्ट मम पुष्करविष्टरायाः ॥ ८॥
>
> The higher worlds like Swarga which are difficult of attainment
>   and for which great sacrifices like Ashwamedha are performed
>   become easily attainable by the compassion filled look of the
>   lotus eyes of MahalakShmi . May she look at me so that I may
>   attain my heart's desires.
>
> दद्याद्दयानुपवनो द्रविणाम्बुधारां
>   अस्मिन्नकिञ्चनविहङ्गशिशौ विषण्णे ।
>
> दुष्कर्मधर्ममपनीय चिराय दूरं
>   नारायणप्रणयिनीनयनाम्बुवाहः ॥ ९॥
>
> The dark rain clouds driven by the monsoon winds
>   releases rain on the parched earth and quench the
>   thirst of the Chataka bird and brings prosperity on the
>   earth. In like manner may the dark eyes of MahalakShmi
>   resembling the rain cloud wafted by the breeze of compassion
>   relese the rain of prosperity on this devotee of a Chataka
>   bird stricken with the load of accumulated sins so that
>   the sins are washed away and prosperity bestowed upon him.
>
> गीर्देवतेति गरुडध्वजसुन्दरीति
>   शाकम्भरीति शशिशेखरवल्लभेति ।
>
> सृष्टिस्थितिप्रलयकेलिषु संस्थितायै
>   तस्यै नमस्त्रिभुवनैकगुरोस्तरुण्यै ॥ १०॥
>
> We offer obeisance to the Goddess MahalakShmi,
>   the consort of Narayana, the preceptor of all the three
>   worlds. She is variously known as Saraswati the Goddess
>   of Learning, as Goddess LakShmi, the Divine consort
>   of Mahavishnu, as Shakambhari or as Parvati the consort
>   of Lord Maheshwara. Verily it is she who is playfully engaged
>   in creation, protaction and final destruction of the Universe
>
> श्रुत्यै नमोऽस्तु शुभकर्मफलप्रसूत्यै
>   रत्यै नमोऽस्तु रमणीयगुणार्णवायै ।
>
> शक्त्यै नमोऽस्तु शतपत्रनिकेतनायै
>   पुष्ट्यै नमोऽस्तु पुरुषोत्तमवल्लभायै ॥ ११॥
>
> O Goddess as the very manifestation of the Vedas,
>   you grant the fruits of godd action. Beautiful in form like
>   Rati Devi you are the very ocean of superlatively
>   beautiful qualities. Having your abode in the beautiful
>   lotus of a hundred petals, you are Shakti personified.
>   O consort of Purushottama, You are the Goddess of
>   plenty. Please accept my obeisance
>
> नमोऽस्तु नालीकनिभाननायै
>   नमोऽस्तु दुग्धोदधिजन्मभूम्यै ।
>
> नमोऽस्तु सोमामृतसोदरायै
>   नमोऽस्तु नारायणवल्लभायै ॥ १२॥
>
> O Consort of Narayana! Whose face is as beautiful
>   as the lotus in bloom, I bow down to thee . Born
>   out of the milky ocean, along with the moon and the
>   Divine nectar, O Goddess! accept my pranams.
>
> नमोऽस्तु हेमाम्बुजपीठिकायै
>   नमोऽस्तु भूमण्डलनायिकायै ।
>
> नमोऽस्तु देवादिदयापरायै
>   नमोऽस्तु शार्ङ्गायुधवल्लभायै ॥ १३॥
>
> I prostrate before you, O Goddess, who are seated
>   on the Golden Lotus, who is Goddess of the earth, the
>   consort of Narayana, compassionate to the Devas.
>
> नमोऽस्तु  देव्यै भृगुनन्दनायै
>   नमोऽस्तु विष्णोरुरसि स्थितायै ।
>
> नमोऽस्तु लक्ष्म्यै कमलालयायै
>   नमोऽस्तु दामोदरवल्लभायै ॥ १४॥
>
> My obeisance to you, O daughter of Bhrigu, consort
>   of Damadara. O LakShmi, seated on Lotus and adorning
>   the broad chest of Mahavishnu, my salutations to Thee.
>
> नमोऽस्तु कान्त्यै कमलेक्षणायै
>   नमोऽस्तु भूत्यै भुवनप्रसूत्यै ।
>
> नमोऽस्तु देवादिभिरर्चितायै
>   नमोऽस्तु नन्दात्मजवल्लभायै ॥ १५॥
>
> O Consort of Gopala, the son of Nanda, you
>   are worshipped by the Devas. You are Jyoti
>   incarnate, I prostrate before Thee. Your eyes
>   are like lotus petals. You have created the world
>   and you bestow prosperity. Please accept my
>   salutations.
>
> सम्पत्कराणि सकलेन्द्रियनन्दनानि
>   साम्राज्यदानविभवानि सरोरुहाक्षि ।
>
> त्वद्वन्दनानि दुरितोद्धरणोद्यतानि
>   मामेव मातरनिशं कलयन्तु मान्ये ॥ १६॥
>
> May I always have the desire to prostrate before you
>   because a pranam to you is capable of bestowing all
>   prosperity and will bring happiness to all the senses.
>   Worshipping O Lotus-eyed Goddess not only removes
>   all miseries but it confers happiness and plenty.
>
> यत्कटाक्षसमुपासनाविधिः
>   सेवकस्य सकलार्थसम्पदः ।
>
> संतनोति वचनाङ्गमानसैः
>   त्वां मुरारिहृदयेश्वरीं भजे ॥ १७॥
>
> The devotee who worships your KatakSha (sidelong
>   glance) is blessed with wealth and prosperity. To you,
>   the queen who dominates the heart of Vishnu, my
>   pranamas, through word, thought, and deed.
>
> सरसिजनिलये सरोजहस्ते
>   धवलतमांशुकगन्धमाल्यशोभे ।
>
> भगवति हरिवल्लभे मनोज्ञे
>   त्रिभुवनभूतिकरि प्रसीद मह्यम् ॥ १८॥
>
> Seated on the lotus with the lotus flower in your hand,
>   dresed in dazzling white and adorned with garlands and
>   sandalwood paste, you gladden our hearts. O Goddess,
>   the consort of Vishnu you who confer prosperity on all
>   the three worlds, please show compassion towards me.
>
> दिग् हस्तिभिः कनककुंभमुखावसृष्ट-
>   स्वर्वाहिनीविमलचारुजलप्लुताङ्गीम् ।
>
> प्रातर्नमामि जगतां जननीमशेष-
>   लोकाधिनाथगृहिणीममृताब्धिपुत्रीम् ॥ १९॥
>
> O mother of all the worlds, consort of Vishnu the lord of
>   the Universe, the Dig-gajas (the celestial elephants guarding
>   various directions) bathe you everyday with waters of the
>   Deva Ganga poured ouitfrom golden vessels. O daughter of
>   the milky ocean, I prostrate before Thee.
>
> कमले कमलाक्षवल्लभे त्वं
>   करुणापूरतरङ्गितैरपाङ्गैः ।
>
> अवलोकय मामकिञ्चनानां
>   प्रथमं पात्रमकृत्रिमं दयायाः ॥ २०॥
>
> O Goddess LakShmi, consort of the Lotus-eyed
>   Mahavishnu, direct your gaze filled with compassion
>   at me, your devotee who am the poorest of the poor,
>   so that I may become the true recipient of the benefits
>   of your compassion.
>
> देवि प्रसीद जगदीश्वरि लोकमातः
>   कल्याणगात्रि कमलेक्षणजीवनाथे ।
>
> दारिद्र्यभीतिहृदयं शरणागतं माम्
>   आलोकय प्रतिदिनं सदयैरपाङ्गैः ॥ २१॥
>
> O Goddess, controller of the Universe and protector
>   of the people, blessing with your limbs, and gazing with
>   your lotus-like eyes, forgive me. With my heart filled with
>   fear of poverty, I surrender myself wholly to you, that you
>   may watch over me every day with unbroken compassion.
>
> स्तुवन्ति ये स्तुतिभिरमीभिरन्वहं
>   त्रयीमयीं त्रिभुवनमातरं रमाम् ।
>
> गुणाधिका गुरुतरभाग्यभागिनो
>   भवन्ति ते भुवि बुधभाविताशयाः ॥ २२॥
>
> Those who sing the praise of MahalakShmi who
>   is the vedas personified, by these stotras everyday
>   will be blessed with all good qualities, unsurpassed
>   good fortune and powers of the intellect which will
>   earn praise from even the learned

Comment: This is a vedic mantra and not everyone has adhikara to recite it. An alternative for those of us that cannot chant vedic mantras is the kanakadhara stavam by sankaracharya.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I have added Kanakadhara Stotra to my answer.

Comment: I think the asker wanted a verse or a mantra, if he wanted stotrams then there are few other apart from the kanakadhara stotram.In fact i used to recite one stotram called the "Ksipraphala Prada Dhanada Or Dhanalakshmi stotram"(the Stotram for achieving wealth in short time),.I think Lord Shiva himself is the seer for that stotram.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks. I also think the same and at the same time I think we can recite any of the verses of Sri Suktam independently too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [famous verse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15619/3500) (don't recall source):

> Arogyam bhaskarad ichcheth
>   Sriyam ichcheth uthasanath
>   Iswarath jnana manvichcheth
>   Moksham ichcheth janardanath

Those who want health, pray to Bhaskara (Sun)
Similarly from Agni, get wealth
From Shiva, get knowledge
From Vishnu, get moksha

Mantras for specific desires are very rare, and must be obtained by proper humility from correct guru, and then chanted with all rules, regulations & bhakti for them to have any effect, or they can have bad opposite effects. There are shlokas I'm aware of for wealth (although I didn't try them with intention of gaining wealth for myself, but only say them as duty).

It is like asking to get PhD in 1 week. It cannot be done easily. I'd suggest you ask your family elders, guru, local temple priest or pray to god with devotion for guidance.

Comment: That is not a wealth verse at all! The one you included says that to get wealth, pray to Agni. You also said there are shlokas for wealth, then why didn't you post them?

Comment: Yes, that is not a wealth verse. I didn't post the shlokas because this is a public board. Mantras only have effect if they are in secret, they should be Ashadkarna meaning - not for 6 ears, i.e. only for 4 ears i.e. only between 2 people i.e. guru & shishya. That's why I asked him to approach one.

Comment: If the mantras won't work if posted here, then that is good so just post them. Nothing will happen but atleast people will know that this is the verse used for wealth.

Comment: And I don't think a guru will ever tell shishya this kind of mantra. Guru is the one who guides you towards your goal, i.e, Moksha and not recommend you to get material pleasures.

Comment: If a mantra is chanted wrong, it can give negative effect i.e. losing what wealth you already have. So, when you say "nothing will happen", that is not true.

Comment: Not all shishyas want Moksha. If a Guru only showed the method to moksha, not many people will even care to approach him. A guru slowly ropes in people by giving them small material pleasures, increasing their faith bit-by-bit, until they develop full bhakthi and surrender.

Comment: First of all, if Shishya are not interested in the highest goal, then guru won't take them as his shishya because spirituality should not be imposed. There is no "real" guru who will ever give someone material pleasure. A real guru will not do that in any case. If you want to know what a "real" guru is then read "Autobiography of a Yogi" and "Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master"

Comment: Nah, there are different grades of shishyas. Being able to raise even the lowest people is the strength and grace and kindness of a great Guru. If a shishya is already so refined to be a mumukshu, the work of guru is very less. God is ready to grant all 4 purusha-arthas - dharma,artha,kama,moksha. So gurus can show the path for the same, not only for moksha. And I don't believe "real" gurus write autobiographies, which are self-extolling in many cases, and especially not in english. We each have our opinions, so no point in continuing this discussion.

Comment: @ram - if i recollect it correctly, the verse you have quoted is from Matsya Purana. Need to further check the exact verse number and the chapter.

Answer (score 0):

श्रीगुरु चरन सरोज रज निज मनु मुकुरु सुधारि।

बरनउँ रघुबर बिमल जसु जो दायकु फल चारि॥

जब तें रामु ब्याहि घर आए। नित नव मंगल मोद बधाए॥

भुवन चारिदस भूधर भारी। सुकृत मेघ बरषहि सुख बारी॥

रिधि सिधि संपति नदीं सुहाई। उमगि अवध अंबुधि कहुँ आई॥

मनिगन पुर नर नारि सुजाती। सुचि अमोल सुंदर सब भाँती॥

कहि न जाइ कछु नगर बिभूती। जनु एतनिअ बिरंचि करतूती॥

सब बिधि सब पुर लोग सुखारी। रामचंद मुख चंदु निहारी॥

Rancharit Manas chaupai to [remove poverty](https://radhe-radhe.net/ramayan-chaupai-to-remove-poverty/)

Link from [radhe-radhe.net](https://radhe-radhe.net)